# Oracle DBMS - Read a table before processing Updating in an AFTER trigger - mutating table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been experimenting with Oracle over the past few weeks and I've stumbled upon an issue which I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I am building a small property management system and I am trying to process as many actions as possible on the database side (purely experimental, I just wanted to clear this up before anyone asks, "why dont you just update these rows through the client")

In my system, I have a properties and rooms table (simplified schema below):

```
`-------------------------------
`           PROPERTIES
`-------------------------------
`- PropertyID:          PK 
`- PropertyStatus:      VARCHAR
`------------------------------- 

`-------------------------------
`            ROOMS
`-------------------------------
`- RoomID:              PK 
`- PropertyID:          FK
`- RoomStatus:          VARCHAR
`-------------------------------
```

Whenever a user is assigned to a room the rooms status is updated to `OCCUPIED`, once this happens I wish to check how many rooms associated with property `n` are taken, if all rooms are taken the property_status should be Updated to `FULL`, then if users are unassigned from properties the value updates to `VACANCIES AVAILABLE` etc.

I have the basic logic for this mapped out:

```
-- Return how many vacant rooms belong to this property
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prop_vacancy_query(
   p_property_id       properties.property_id%TYPE
)
RETURN NUMBER
   IS 
v_prop_rooms NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(room_status) 
   INTO v_prop_rooms
   FROM rooms 
     JOIN properties ON
     rooms.property_id = properties.property_id
     WHERE room_status = 'VACANT'
     AND rooms.property_id = p_property_id;
  RETURN v_prop_rooms;
END prop_vacancy_query;
```

In my AFTER trigger on my rooms table I try to call the query but I get a mutating table error, I believe this is because `prop_vacancy_query` is reading the properties table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_rooms_after
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON rooms FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- Update the table based on the result
IF prop_vacancy_query(:NEW.property_id) = 0 THEN
    UPDATE properties
    SET prop_status = 'VACANT'
    WHERE properties.property_id = :NEW.property_id;
ELSE
    UPDATE properties
    SET prop_status = 'FULL'
    WHERE properties.property_id = :NEW.property_id;
END IF;
END;
```

Previously this code worked for my system, but since reading more into `pragma autonomous transactions` I have realised it was extremely bad practice to run the `prop_vacancy_query()` on its own independent transaction.

Is there any way that I can read from the properties table and then update the rooms table without getting a mutating error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, the mutating table exception is thrown because you are trying to read from the `rooms` table in your function, not because you are trying to read from the `properties` table.  Since you have a row-level trigger on `rooms`, that means that the `rooms` table is in the middle of a change when the row-level trigger is firing and that it may be in an inconsistent state.  Oracle prevents you from querying the `rooms` table in that situation because the results are not necessarily deterministic or reproducible.

If you created a statement-level trigger (removing the `FOR EACH ROW`) and put your logic there, you would no longer encounter a mutating table exception because the `rooms` table would no longer be in an inconsistent state.  A statement-level trigger, though, is not able to see which row(s) were modified.  That would mean that you'd need to look across all properties to see which status values should be adjusted.  That's not going to be particularly efficient.

At the cost of additional complexity, you can improve the performance by capturing which properties changed in a row-level trigger and then referring to that in a statement-level trigger.  That generally requires three triggers and a package, which obviously increases the number of moving pieces substantially (if you're on 11.2, you can use a compound trigger with three component triggers which simplifies things a bit by eliminating the need to use the package).  That would look something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE trigger_collections
AS
  TYPE modified_property_tbl IS TABLE OF properties.property_id%type;
  g_modified_properties modified_property_tbl;
END;

-- Initialize the collection in a before statement trigger just in case
-- there were values there from a prior run
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_initialize_mod_prop_coll
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON rooms
BEGIN
  trigger_collections.g_modified_properties := trigger_collections.modified_property_tbl();
END;

-- Put the property_id of the modified row in the collection
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_populate_mod_prop_coll
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON rooms
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  trigger_collections.g_modified_properties.extend();
  trigger_collections.g_modified_properties( trigger_collections.g_modified_properties.count + 1 ) := :new.property_id;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_process_mod_prop_coll
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON rooms
BEGIN
  FOR p IN 1 .. trigger_collections.g_modified_properties.count
  LOOP
    IF prop_vacancy_query( trigger_collections.g_modified_properties(i) ) = 0 
    THEN
      ...
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Justin the solution and explanation has cleared the confusion I had on this matter! :)