# Oracle - How to force user to INSERT multiple row

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle 11gR2 on an Academic Assignment. There is a constraint which a room must have 3 - 5 people. I know that I can write a Trigger like this to check if a room has more than 5 people:

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
  PID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Room
(
  RID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Living
(
  RID INTEGER,
  PID INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT Living_PK PRIMARY KEY (RID, PID),
  CONSTRAINT Living_FK_RID FOREIGN KEY (RID) REFERENCES Room(RID),
  CONSTRAINT Living_FK_PID FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES People(PID)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Living_BIU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Living
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  Count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO Count
    FROM Living
    WHERE RID = :NEW.RID;
  IF(Count > 5)
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Too many people in a room.');
  END IF;
END Living_BI;
```

But I can not check if the number is lesser than 3 because then I can not insert any things into Living. So my question is how can I create a trigger that force user to insert more than 3 rows and less than 5 rows at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard preface that this isn't how you would really do this sort of thing in the real world...

You would realistically need to use a statement-level trigger here.  If you don't mind the performance hit of checking every room every time

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Living_AIUD
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON Living
DECLARE
  Count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT rid, count(*) cnt
              FROM living
             GROUP BY rid
            HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
  LOOP
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Too few people in room ' || x.rid);
  END LOOP;
END Living_AIUD;
```

If you don't want to check this for every room every time, you'd need a package with a collection of `rid` values, a before statement trigger that initialized the collection, and a row-level trigger that added the `:new.rid` value to the collection.  Your after statement trigger would then iterate over the elements in the collection and check the number of people in just those rooms.

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie in this, can you explain what is "package" and "collection"?

Comment: @Tr1et - You can see an example of this sort of approach in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115966/oracle-dbms-read-a-table-before-processing-updating-in-an-after-trigger-muta/23118466#23118466  If you haven't learned about collections or packages in your class yet, I would assume that your professor expects the simpler, less efficient approach I outlined in my answer.

Comment: So when that APPLICATION_ERROR rise, the row is inserted or it is blocked?

Comment: @Tr1et - If an error is raised, the statement fails and the work that statement had done to that point is rolled back.

Comment: OK, I understand now, so it's only drawback is it check all room, but does that mean that when a room have too few people then I can not insert to the other rooms?

Comment: @Tr1et - If a room has too few occupants then, yes, you would be unable to insert occupants in another room.  Since you're trying to prevent that situation from occurring, though, that doesn't seem like a problem you need to be concerned with (i.e. the trigger will mostly prevent you from being in the situation where room A has only 2 occupants thus preventing you from inserting occupants into room B).  That doesn't work in real systems where multiple users can be modifying data simultaneously but it's probably enough for a homework assignment.